# write code for the autogenerated button in datagridview in c#,asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to write code for the button(delete button)in each row  generated inside a datagridview in asp.net.

whenever I double click on the button inside the datagridview it takes me to the gridview field in c# and not to the button click event

Answer (score 0):

This should point in the right direction:

```
private void yourDataGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        // do something => e.RowIndex
    }
}
```

*Just as much effort as you've got.*